# Spree Hub Integration Panel is not visible in Rails 4 Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have successfully integrated Spree Hub with my Spree Store front application and it works like a charm in Development mode.

But when I switch to Production Environment, then the Integration Panels body section seems blank.

It only shows the "INTEGRATION" tab at the top, but it's further Configuration panel(for adding a new connection) is not Visible in the page.

***My rails version : Rails 4 
& Spree Version : 2.1.3***

[image: Blank Spree Hub Integration Panel]

Comment: Can you drop an email to support@spreecommerce.com to make sure we get this taken care of?

Odds are it's a javascript issue.